# SQLite [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "',pass='": syntax error)

Tags: sql, sqlite

in the camp I am at we were given an assignments to try to do some basic SQL injection.

There is a table named `info` with a few fields. There is a field named `id`, a field named `sum` and a field named `pass`.

What I am trying to do is given some id change both the `sum` and the `pass` matching that `id`.

What I was trying to do is:

```
http://a/b/c/withdraw?id=123456789&sum=7312',pass='weak
```

But I am getting this error:

```
[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "',pass='": syntax error)
```

When I do this:

```
http://a/b/c/withdraw?id=123456789&sum=7312
```

The `sum` field changes successfully, but I need to change the password matching the id as well.

Can anyone here tell me what's the problem?

Comment: What are single quotes in your request standing for?

Comment: @SviatoslavMelnychenko, I am trying to make the sql engine parse the string as: UPDATE info set sum='7312',pass='weak' WHERE id='123456789'

Comment: I'm guessing you're not making use of parameters in prepared statements and binding values to them.